# Twitter API for popular tweets

Tags: api, twitter

Is their any Twitter API that can be accessed without authentication for - 
1.) post by user and users Followers that are being Tweeted/re-twitted the most 
and
2.) users tweets that users followers have clicked on or re-twitted the most

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According the the [API v1 docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), this is possible, by including `result_type=popular` in the query string of your request.

For example, if you wanted to search for popular tweets relating to the search term `popular tweets`, your request would be as follows:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=popular%20tweets&result_type=popular

Comment: Well, that API is dead now.